# Why is a semicolon needed here?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6

I am simply using es6 to reassign variables a & b. Why do I get an error if I leave the semicolon off of the a and b declaration and assignment statements? Does the parser try to pull a property out of 2 if the semicolon is left off? let b = 2[a, b]...?

```
Works:
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
[a, b] = [b, a]

Error:
```

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

I am looking for the actual reason this fails. Thanks!

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: Do you have a "use strict" somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the parser try to pull a property out of 2 if the semicolon is left off? let b = 2[a, b]...?

Yes.  You cannot safely start a statement with a `[` if you're not explicitly ending statements with semicolons.

This has been written about in many places, and it's one of the many things that standardJS (or other linters) will warn you about: http://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons

Comment: @brso05 This is because it is parsed as `let b = 2[a, b] = [b, a]`, meaning you're trying to reference `b` *inside* the definition of `b`.